# extract all values from response complex json in java

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, gson

I am trying to extract all values from 
http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dic&q=keyword&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr%2Cde&client=te

and I want to use GSON, but I cant figure out what to do with it.

Is there anything that is similar to jericohtml parser which can just simply extract all values?

also, i need to use java.
i can retrieve json, but it's not regularly formated( i mean line by line written)

thanks

```
URL u=new URL(url);
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/atom+xml");
     conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0");

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String temp=br.readLine();
    String strJson=temp.substring("dic(".length(),temp.length()-",200,null)".length());

    System.out.println(strJson);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can you gson to extract your jsonobject and set you your user defined object 
[click here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) for example

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("c:\\file.json"));

        //convert the json string back to object
        DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class);

        System.out.println(obj);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: but I need to extract values, not convert from string to object